# showing TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tryPointToLocation') while adding BingMap (bingmaps-react v^1.2.10) in Nexjs v13

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I for last many days I have been trying to add BingMap (bingmaps-react v^1.2.10) in Nexjs v13, But I am constantly getting the error

> 'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tryPointToLocation')'

at line `let infobox = await new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox(map.getCenter(), {`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5Ije.png)

```js
const map = await new Microsoft.Maps.Map(this.mapRef.current, {})
    const pushpinClicked = (e: any) => {
      if (e.target.metadata) {
        infobox.setOptions({
          location: e.target.getLocation(),
          title: e.target.metadata.title,
          description: e.target.metadata.description,
          visible: true,
        })
      }
    }

    console.log('map', map);
    
    let infobox = await new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox(map.getCenter(), {
      visible: false,
    })

    //Assign the infobox to a map instance.
    infobox.setMap(map)
```

I expect the BingMap to appear on the page